# How to send post data to the server in angular datatables?

Tags: angular-datatables

please provide any code or any example or any link.

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource( baseApi + '/NH/dashboard' ).withFnServerParams( serverParams );
            function serverParams ( aoData ) {
                aoData.push( jsonObj );
            }
```

it gives error..

```
DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(...).withFnServerParams is not a function
```

Comment: I believe the error message is crystal clear: "*withFnServerParams is not a function*".    Code and examples becomes available if you type "angular datatables" in a google search.

Comment: Do you look like Alien ??

This is the documentation link..
http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnServerData

If you don't know the answer then don't comment with your shit.

Comment: Yes, but this is not implemented in **angular datatables**, has never been. You simply invent something that never have existed in angular dataTables. And your reference is legacy code, have been deprecated in +3 years, no longer maintained in jQuery dataTables itself (thats why the url is **legacy**.datatables.net). Dont be angry at me, I just tell you the truth, and the truth is not "shit" :)

Comment: "this is not implemented in angular datatables"-- If you said this in your first comment, then I would have never used "shit" to you :)

Comment: As said: The error message "*withFnServerParams is not a function*" is crystal clear.